# What would be a good approach to migrate Aurora data into a Redshift DWH?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl, aws-glue, amazon-aurora

We need to move and consolidate data from various Aurora databases into a Redshift one.

Since our endpoints are AWS services we are learning about Glue, Pipeline and also Matillion.

Is it Glue intended to be used in a 'traditional ETL' like this one? Can Glue be used to create and populate fact and dimension tables 'in flight' ?

I read that a common pattern would be to transform data using the apache spark engine that Glue runs on → move data to S3 → move data to Redshift.

Why would be necessary to move the data to a bucket after we apply the dim/fact logic?

Is it practical to create these dim/fact transformations using Python/Scala (since Glue doesn't have UI transformations)?

I'm also learning that in some cases it's more efficient to store data in Redshift keeping the same structure as the origin (no facts/dim). Is there a rule to try to see when this would be the case?

Matillion looks like a good option (similar to SSIS) but seems a bit expensive.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If your Aurora databases are Postgres based then I recommend starting with [Redshift's Federated Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/federated-overview.html). FQ allows you to directly query your Aurora Postgres tables from Redshift. Using FQ you can set up a simple sync process to bring the data into Redshift from Aurora (see these [example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/StoredProcedures/sp_sync_merge_changes.sql) [SPs](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/StoredProcedures/sp_sync_get_new_rows.sql)).

If your Aurora DBs are MySQL based or your data volumes are extremely large you may want to start by [exporting the data from Aurora to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html) and then [loading the extracts to Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html).

As you gain familiarity with Redshift you can add distribution keys and sort keys to your tables to improve performance. [Redshift Advisor will suggest effective distribution keys and sort keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/advisor-recommendations.html#alter-diststyle-distkey-recommendation) based on the queries you run.

This process should allow you to get started with Redshift quickly and then you can start using Glue or Matillion later when you need their unique and specific abilities.